# Loop not stops in condition

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops, conditional-statements

I was just trying to display a particular content in a loop in list and after a condition is met it should display in a div.This is what i have tried

```
function the_meta() {
  if ( $keys = get_post_custom_keys() ) {
    echo "<ul class='post-meta'>\n";
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( (array) $keys as $key ) {

        $keyt = trim($key);

        if ( is_protected_meta( $keyt, 'post' ) )
            continue;

        $values = array_map('trim', get_post_custom_values($key));
        $value = implode($values,', ');
        echo apply_filters('the_meta_key', "<li id='slots_".$key."'><span class='post-meta-key'>$key:</span> $value</li>\n", $key, $value);

        if (++$i > 8)
           echo apply_filters('the_meta_key', "<div><span class='post-meta-key'>$key:</span> $value</div>\n", $key, $value);

    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
  }
}
```

what I am getting is as follows

```
<ul class='post-meta'>
   <li id='slots_Numeri_estratti_1'><span class='post-meta-key'>Numeri_estratti_1:</span> 22</li>
   <li id='slots_numeri_estratti_2'><span class='post-meta-key'>numeri_estratti_2:</span> 23</li>
   <li id='slots_numeri_estratti_3'><span class='post-meta-key'>numeri_estratti_3:</span> 24</li>
   <li id='slots_numeri_estratti_4'><span class='post-meta-key'>numeri_estratti_4:</span> 25</li>
   <li id='slots_numeri_estratti_5'><span class='post-meta-key'>numeri_estratti_5:</span> 26</li>
   <li id='slots_numeri_estratti_6'><span class='post-meta-key'>numeri_estratti_6:</span> 27</li>
   <li id='slots_numeri_estratti_7'><span class='post-meta-key'>numeri_estratti_7:</span> 28</li>
   <li id='slots_numeri_estratti_8'><span class='post-meta-key'>numeri_estratti_8:</span> Concorso Nr. 36 - Montepremi complessivo € 10.474.698,21</li>
   <li id='slots_numeri_estratti_9'><span class='post-meta-key'>numeri_estratti_9:</span> 21</li>
   <div id='slots_numeri_estratti_9'><span class='post-meta-key'>numeri_estratti_9:</span> 21</div>
   <li id='slots_numeri_estratti_10'><span class='post-meta-key'>numeri_estratti_10:</span> 33</li>
   <div id='slots_numeri_estratti_10'><span class='post-meta-key'>numeri_estratti_10:</span> 33</div>
</ul>
```

The values are displaying twice, one in list and other in div.I have been searching on Google for hours and couldn't get any results to solve it.Someone please help me .Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this

```
if (++$i > 8)
    echo apply_filters('the_meta_key', "<div><span class='post-meta-key'>$key:</span> $value</div>\n", $key, $value);
else
    echo apply_filters('the_meta_key', "<li id='slots_".$key."'><span class='post-meta-key'>$key:</span> $value</li>\n", $key, $value);
```

rather than

```
echo apply_filters('the_meta_key', "<li id='slots_".$key."'><span class='post-meta-key'>$key:</span> $value</li>\n", $key, $value);

if (++$i > 8)
    echo apply_filters('the_meta_key', "<div><span class='post-meta-key'>$key:</span> $value</div>\n", $key, $value);
```

Comment: ok when i am trying to give a table instead of div, the tables are displaying twice with the values. Any help? I have tried if (++$i > 8){
  echo "<table><thead><tr><td>Categoria</td><td>N. vincite</td><td>Euro</td></tr></thead>";
    echo apply_filters('the_meta_key', "<tbody><tr><td>$value</td><td>$key</td><td>-</td></tr></table>", $key, $value);
}else
    echo apply_filters('the_meta_key', "<li id='slots_".$key."'><span class='post-meta-key'>$key:</span> $value</li>\n", $key, $value);
   
  }

Comment: remove this statement and put just before `foreach` statement `echo "<table><thead><tr><td>Categoria</td><td>N. vincite</td><td>Euro</td></tr></thead>";`

Comment: and also you need to rewrite your app as it is making your html untidy with table, div and li inside ul nested incorrectly

Comment: hi thanks and that worked.ls there any possibility where i can call on more custom value under the third row ie.. Euro. Where the user enters the custom field and it displays in different rows?please help thanks!

Comment: Yes you can, create function and call it from there.

Comment: Can you please help me out on how to create that function.I am really a newbie in php .Thanks!!